# Should old openings in a plywood roof deck be closed before installing steel?

Tags: roof, metal, roofing, venting

My metal roofer removed all 14 old vents and installed two new "Maximum ventilators" in its place. The remaining 12 holes are still there and not sealed and i can see the underside of the metal roof from the attic. The roofer claims that the holes serve as additional ventilation and that air will make its way out the old vent holes to the underside of the metal roof and out thru the ridge. But the manufacturer of the maximum vent says to seal off all old vents to prevent a short circuit in air flow as air should be pulled from tge soffits.

Whats the right way[image]

Comment: Was any of this addressed in the contract?  What's the gap between the wood and metal?

Comment: Would go with the manufacturer of the vents, they should know how the vents work best, not a roofer.

Comment: Wow that would fail inspection in my jurisdiction, I would check with your building codes devision.

Comment: What happens down the road when someone is walking on the roof and steps where the hole is?  Best case, there is now a big dent there.  Worst case there is now a hole in your roof.  No, this is not acceptable!

Comment: Are you sure you're seeing metal and not the underlayment?

Comment: which steel product was used?

Comment: If the metal deck is directly laying on the plywood roof deck, then yes, you shall close those old openings. If the metal decks are laid over their own supports (purlins), then talk to your HVAC guy about how to ventilate the space between the two roofs, as both roof materials need fresh air for breath. But I highly doubt this is your case.

Comment: My gut instinct runs with everyone else's - that's not acceptable. _However_, not addressed is "How thick is the metal"? If it's thin flashing (will it move when you poke it with a finger?) then no, this isn't acceptable at all. If it's thicker metal, then it _might_ be acceptable, depending on _how_ thick. My gut is telling me that this is just flashing because that's what the roofer has on the truck, but, if he installed something thicker that can support some weight, you're probably OK. If it's thicker, you'll probably see bumps in the shingles from the outside....

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading something that even under asphalt shingles there is an allowable hole size which does not affect the performance of the shingle. I do not recall if this was content in this DIY site or some other forum.

However, I'm sure you're not interested in the aforementioned technicality.

Did the roofer do a sloppy job? Yes.

Does it increase injury risk for future roofers? Yes.

Are they blowing you off by saying it helps with ventilation? Yes.

If there is a gap between your new roof and the sheathing then bugs can more easily get in. At minimum I would screw on a piece of plywood from the bottom to keep bugs out. Just make sure not to penetrate your new metal roof!

I highly doubt you will be able to convince the roofer to rip up the new roof just to patch underlayment.

Comment: Anyway, you could patch the plywood from the underside.  Make a patch the same size (minus 1/8") out of the same material, and then make a picture frame out of 1x2's to use as battens. Choose screw lengths carefully.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure how rich OP is so my solution aims to avoid cashing in a 401K =D

Comment: Your best friend could be your local building inspector!

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary mechanisms by which attics vent... convection, or hot air lift, and scavenging, the mild vacuum created by airflow over the roof. Between the two I doubt your attic will be significantly hotter due to those openings.

Whether they should be closed for other reasons is up for debate. Many steel roofs are installed over purlins, meaning that almost the entire roof is essentially unsupported, and you'd have to walk carefully. Obviously the gaps between purlins are in a more predictable location than these openings, but no one will punch through with a foot. At worst it'll dent.

I'd want them fixed, but it's not a disastrous situation by any stretch. If you want to do it yourself, cut some patches, press them into place, and run a 2x4 across to the adjacent trusses, tight to the deck. Use caulk or spray foam to seal the joint. If you use fasteners into the deck, *be sure they don't protrude even a little*. They'll cause dimples and damage to the steel.